# When detecting outliers for an ANVOA test for multiple groups, should I do this for the whole population sample or by group?

Tags: anova, outliers

I have data that is grouped by 5 groups. I want to check for outliers as part of a one-way anova. Should the check for outliers on the whole sample, or by group? I am using box plots to look for outliers, plus homogeneity of variance plots and qq  plots.

Follow on question. If I identify outliers, but think they are plausible values and want to keep them in, will this affect the results of the anova?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Imagine that most of the groups are clustered together and one group is far away. Would you consider those points to be outliers?

Comment: Great point. I need to look by group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave answered your first question in a comment: Look group by group.

You also asked if it will "affect the results of this ANOVA?"  This is a little trickier question than it appears. Every point will affect your results. Try deleting any observation and re-running and you will see a difference. For most of the points, the differences will be small.

"Outliers" and "influential points" are related but not identical concepts. An influential point is one which, if deleted, would change the results a lot. An outlier is simply a surprising observation. If this point is close to the fit without that point, then it won't be very influential.

This may be clearer with a simpler example and in a regression framework. Suppose you are looking at the relationship between height and weight in men.  If your sample happens to include someone who is very tall and very heavy (say, an offensive lineman in (American) football) then he will be an outlier, but he may not be an influential point.  OTOH, if it includes someone who is very tall but not heavy (say, basketball player Manute Bol, who was 7 foot 7 and only 201 pounds  - 2.3 meters and 90 kg) then he will be a very influential point.

A different issue is that these outliers violate the assumptions of ANOVA and, therefore, you should probably use a model that makes fewer assumptions, such as robust regression or quantile regression.